# Blender 2.8 Making an object with exact dimensions

Tags: modeling

Modeling in 2.8 how can I create this object to the exact size I need.
I need an object with a base dimensions of 50 mm on the X axis and 28 mm on the Y axis. Then I need to raise the z axis to a total height of 14 mm from the bottom.  This is to be used for 3D printing.

In the image, I started with a cube. I entered the values in scale X = 50, Y = 28, Z=2(I need a small connecting plane), I added 2 loop cuts, then extruded the two faces along the edge as I need a small separation between the two (exact separation distance not important).

I can see where I can set the ground/grid to millimeters.  I can see where I turn on the edge dimensions overlay.

I remembered from 2.79 to press Ctrl-A in object mode, select scale then tab into edit mode to display scaled dimensions.

I just don't seem to be able to make sense of the actual dimensions.

If anyone could just describe the simple steps to create a scale object, that would be appreciated.

[image: modeling object to exact dimension]

Comment: You need to apply scale for 3D printing. You will want your object in (1,1,1) scale and rotation. Manipulate every thing in edit mode will be a good pratice.

Comment: Hello and welcome to Blender SE. Please share your file https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/ so others can take a look :).

Comment: @JachymMichal I don't think a blend file is necessary here, the OP has described the exact method they used to create the geometry and is easily recreatable.

Comment: @Hikariztw perhaps you could write up your comment as an answer, providing solutions as comments breaks the mechanism of the site and leaves the question *unanswered*.

Comment: @Merlin This question contain a lot of aspect to be answered. I don't think a single comment can solve all the problem once and for all. So I rather choose to comment my thought cause I don't really understand what do the OP want in Blender.